Recurrence relation of the type X[n1+1,n2] + X[n1-1,n2] + X[n1,n2+1] + X[n1,n2-1] = q X[n1,n2]. RSolve not OK
I need to solve a recurrence relation of the type
       X[n1+1,n2] + X[n1-1,n2] +  X[n1,n2+1] + X[n1,n2-1] = q X[n1,n2]

How do I do this? RSolve does not work.

RSolve does not work because there is no boundary condition. This recursion is two dimensional problem, so the general solution would depend on infinite number of free parameters.

@A.Kato RSolve works without boundary conditions too: RSolve[a[m + 1, n] - 3/4 a[m, n + 1] == 0, a[m, n], {m, n}] (*{{a[m, n] -> (4/3)^(1 - m) C[1][m + n]}}*)

@UlrichNeumann Because the latter problem is essentially one dimensional: only a[m,n]'s on a line m+n = constant interact with each other. The parameter C[1] depends on m+n, so it still needs infinite number of free parameters.

@A.Kato I just wanted to give an example where the statement RSolve does not work because there is no boundary condition is not correct.

@UlrichNeumann You are right. Sorry.  I should have said in the case of the OP's problem boundary conditions are necessary. In the a[m + 1, n] - 3/4 a[m, n + 1] == 0 case, an affine change of indices a[m,n] -> b[m, m+n] makes the second index redundant, which is presumably the strategy RSolve used.

This equation can be solved by performing a Fourier or Laplace transform in one dimension, applying RSolve, and then inverting the transform.  I believe that RSolve cannot handle the problem without a transform, because the range of possible solutions depends on the boundary conditions selected, as suggested by @A.Kato
